# Python: Increasing Dates with each Loop

Tags: python, datetime

For a current project, I am planning to increase the value of a calendar date by 3 months with each iteration/loop. The value for `start_date` should hence be `[1st iteration]: 01/01/2017, [2nd interation] 01/04/2017` etc. For `end_date`, it should accordingly yield `[1st iteration]: 31/03/2017, [2nd interation] 30/06/2017` etc.

I originally thought it would be a simple point to solve but somehow the script is not working as planned (also as many threads discuss how to increase values in one go but not how to perform this in several loops). Does anyone know how to tweak things?

The corresponding code looks as follows:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

for i in df.iterrows():
    start_date = '01/01/2017'
    start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+3)
    end_date = '31/03/2017'
    end_date = end_date + relativedelta(months=+3)

    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are initialising the `start_date` and `end_date` inside the loop. Just initialise them once outside the loop, then continue process like you're doing.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

# year, month, day
start_date = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2017, 3, 31)

for i in df.iterrows():
    start_date += relativedelta(months=3)
    end_date += relativedelta(months=3)

    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is yielding the error `start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+3) - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "relativedelta") to str` though. Let me figure out how this can be solved.

Comment: See my edit. Parsing the values as dates should get the job done.

Comment: It's an invalid token apparently `(SyntaxError: invalid token)`. Currently checking if a different separator helps.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. You have to remove the zeros. Also, make sure you have the day and month in the correct order.

Comment: Yup saw that as well - thanks for checking though :)

Comment: One last error I am currently checking until it should hopefully be running is `ValueError: day is out of range for month`. Referring to the line `start_date = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)`

Comment: hmm, that's strange. Works for me. Maybe try: `datetime.date.fromisoformat('2017-01-01')`.

Comment: Glad I helped :) Cheers.